# Failure sending email from and to same host with postfix operating as relay host

Tags: postfix

My personal server runs postfix and its own DNS (bind9).  Postfix was set up to forward email to a Gmail account.  For the sake of this question, please assume that the server's FQDN is `example.com` .

I'm having an issue where whenever I send email to valid email addresses on `example.com` (say `fooser@example.com`), postfix attempts to deliver the email locally and fails with the log message `Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; unknown user: fooser` .

Postfix's `mydestination` setting is set to `example.com` and bind9 is configured to resolve the same domain and several of its subdomains.  I don't understand why Postfix is behaving in this manner when it is configured to run as a relay host:

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options =
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Sending emails to non-`example.com` address works just fine.

Is there a way to force postfix to *always* forward emails, irrespective of destination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a total postfix noob.  It seems that simply changing postfix's `mydestination` and `myhostname` settings as well as the contents of `/etc/mailname` to `foobar.baz` (not `example.com`) fixed the issue.

Unclear though if all these settings need to be changed.

**EDIT**
Just found out that I had to set `myorigin` to the server's FQDN, which in my case is `example.com`, to finally achieve mapping of local user mail (`user@localhost`) to a particular email address (`support@example.com`).  Mapping of local user mail was achieved using a virtual alias map (`virtual_alias_map` setting).